# SSL-сертификат принцип работы

Tags: ssl, https, tls

Объясните пожалуйста про удостоверяющие SSL-сертификаты. Сколько не читал так и не смог понять механизма их работы.

Как я понимаю SSL-Сертификаты ввели, как противодействие перехвата публичных ключей в асимметричном шифровании, подмену этих ключей и как итог расшифровка, просушка и изменение зашифрованого трафика между Клиентом и Сервером.

Поэтому прежде, чем обменяться публичными ключами, Сервер на GET-запрос Клиента сначала посылает ему удостоверяющий Сертификат.

И тут все, я ничего не понимаю.

-Что из себя представляет этот сертификат?

-как тут задействуется Удостоверяющий центр и его цифровая подпись ?

-Почему нельзя перехватить сертификат и подсунуть свой ? итд...

Comment: «противодействие перехвата публичных ключей в асимметричном шифровании»  — это чушь. SSL и есть асимметричное шифрование.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, а чушь то в чем  ?

Comment: В том что в перехвате публичных ключей нет никакого смысла. Они **публичные**

Comment: @Alexey Ten, хммм, ну тогда может ответите на вопрос: Зачем придумали Сертификаты то ? Заем они нужны, если трафик зашифрован.

Comment: Так трафик *безопасно* зашифрован именно с их помощью.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, я думал, что можно перехватить публичный ключ, сгенерировать свою пару публичный-закрытый ключ и отослать Клиенту или Серверу - свой Открытый ключ и таким образом можно будет расшифровывать трафик. Разве нет ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141359/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-optimus1).

Answer (score 2):

Если не вдаваться в сложную математику, и совсем на пальцах:

1. В вашей операционной системе (и/или в браузере) уже есть много сертификатов *корневых* УЦ, которые установлены изначально.
2. Когда браузер соединяется с сайтом по https, сайт первым делом отдаёт свой сертификат **подписанный** одним из корневых УЦ (возможно не напрямую, а через цепочку подписей).
3. Браузер (про помощи сложной математики) проверяет что подпись (подписи) настоящие и что сертификат подходит к домену который он запрашивал.
4. Далее (про помощи другой сложной математики) браузер и сервер договариваются о сессионном ключ шифрования
5. и вся дальнейшая переписка между ними шифруется этим ключом.

> Что из себя представляет этот сертификат?

Файл в котором описан срок действия сертификата, для каких доменов он подходит и публичный ключ от асимметричного шифрования. Это файл подписан УЦ  и именно эту подпись проверяет браузер на шаге 3.

> как тут задействуется Удостоверяющий центр и его цифровая подпись?

Владелец сервера заранее подписывает свой файл в УЦ.
УЦ проверяет что домен(-ы) в сертификате действительно принадлежат владельцу сервиса.
Сертификаты корневых УЦ уже есть у вашего браузера.

> Почему нельзя перехватить сертификат и подсунуть свой?

Можно. Но перехватывающий в общем случае не сможет подсунуть свой сертификат для нужного домена с действительной подписью.
Именно из-за этой угрозы все очень скептически смотрят на российские корневые сертификаты, т.к. опасаются что государственный УЦ «забудет» проверить что ООО «Рога и копыта» владеют доменом `google.com`.

Comment: Спасибо, а что из себя представляет Подпись УЦ, что ее не сможет подделать злоумышленник ?

Comment: Обычная электронная подпись https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Answer (score 0):

Сертификат служит для проверки что запрошенный сайт является подлинным, а не кто-то им притворяется. Проверив его подпись по центру сертификации браузер решает доверять ли ему.

В сертификате есть открытый ключ который служит шифрования общего ключа (pre master key) при 4х стороннем обмене ключами шифрования.